# What to do for C++ code with the AudioSession API being completely deprecated?

Tags: c++, ios, core-audio, deprecated, avaudiosession

So the AudioSession API is completely deprecated in iOS 7.0. The [Audio Session Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/index.html) refers to the [AVAudioSession Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240) *for the Objective-C implementation of these functions*.

Well my code is using the C AudioSession API and is written in C++. I would like to keep it that way if possible.

Which C API can I use to replace the deprecated functions? Is there any option?

Comment: I don't think you'll have much choice, other than to convert.  Apple likes to keep both developer and user moving forward like cattle.  Moo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call Objective C class methods (such as those in the  AVAudioSession Class) thru the Objective C runtime library, which is callable from regular C code.

Comment: How would one "call the objective C class methods thru the Objective C runtime library?"  It seems so simple, but not easily googleable.

Comment: Using Objective-C++ (`.mm`) you can mix C++ and Objective-C. Unfortunately you will have to write an Objective-C class to receive the `NSNotification` from `AVAudioSession`